# Meteor angularjs "Node.replaceChild does not implement interface Node" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I use urigo angular package for Meteor.
My app works fine on Chrome, but I get

```
    "Error: Argument 1 of Node.replaceChild does not implement interface Node.
replaceWith@http://localhost:3000/packages/urigo_angular.js?a8f86b8c424846839431f94b241fd8725bbccfee:8065:9
applyDirectivesToNode@http://localhost:3000/packages/urigo_angular.js?a8f86b8c424846839431f94b241fd8725bbccfee:7272:1
```

in Firefox console. :(
Anybody know how to fix it? I followed this tutorial: http://angularjs.meteor.com/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove meteor-polymer and meteor-polymer-elements package.

Comment: Can you please open an issue on that in our library so I can update the tutorial?